How to play HLS Stream in VLC Player
I use this library
// VLC Android
implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:4.0.0-eap14'
but I got this issue when I play hls file, how can I fix it
I am trying to run a fls file in VLC on Android app but I encounter this error during the run process, I don't know if anyone else has encountered this error.
